# Option for removing block not appearing in custom gutenberg block

Tags: block-editor

I'm developing a custom gutenberg block. I'm able to get the fields to appear and I'm able to interact with it when adding it to a page. But the menu that allows you to remove the block does not appear when it's highlighted.
I'm referring to the menu in the screenshot below

[image]

I'm using the esnext syntax and this is what my main block js file looks like

```
    import "./style.scss";
import "./editor.scss";

const { __, setLocaleData } = wp.i18n;
const {
    registerBlockType,
} = wp.blocks;
const {
    RichText,
    MediaUpload,
} = wp.editor;
const { Button } = wp.components;

registerBlockType( 'tc-blocks/hero-block', {
    title: __( 'Hero Block', 'tc-blocks' ),
    icon: 'index-card',
    category: 'layout',
    attributes: {
        title: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'attribute',
            selector: 'h2',
        },
        mediaID: {
            type: 'number',
        },
        mediaURL: {
            type: 'string',
            source: 'attribute',
            selector: 'img',
            attribute: 'src',
        },
    },
    edit: ( props ) => {
        const {
            className,
            attributes: {
                title,
                mediaID,
                mediaURL,
            },
            setAttributes,
        } = props;
        const onChangeTitle = ( value ) => {
            setAttributes( { title: value } );
        };

        const onSelectImage = ( media ) => {
            setAttributes( {
                mediaURL: media.url,
                mediaID: media.id,
            } );
        };

        return (
            <div className={ className }>
                <RichText
                    tagName="h2"
                    placeholder={ __( 'Write Title…', 'tc-blocks' ) }
                    value={ title }
                    onChange={ onChangeTitle }
                />
                <div className="tc-image">
                    <MediaUpload
                        onSelect={ onSelectImage }
                        allowedTypes="image"
                        value={ mediaID }
                        render={ ( { open } ) => (
                            <Button className={ mediaID ? 'image-button' : 'button button-large' } onClick={ open }>
                                { ! mediaID ? __( 'Upload Image', 'tc-blocks' ) : <img src={ mediaURL } alt={ __( 'Upload Image', 'tc-blocks' ) } /> }
                            </Button>
                        ) }
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
    save: ( props ) => {
        const {
            className,
            attributes: {
                title,
                mediaURL,
            },
        } = props;
        return (
            <div className={ className }>
                <RichText.Content tagName="h2" value={ title } />

                {
                    mediaURL && (
                        <img className="tc-image" src={ mediaURL } alt={ __( 'Image', 'tc-blocks' ) } />
                    )
                }
            </div>
        );
    },
} );
```

Here's how I'm registering the block type in my index.php file

```
function tc_blocks_hero_block_block_init() {
    register_block_type_from_metadata( __DIR__ );
}
add_action( 'init', 'tc_blocks_hero_block_block_init' );
```

And here's my block.json file

```
{
"apiVersion": 2,
"name": "tc-blocks/hero-block",
"title": "Hero Block",
"category": "widgets",
"icon": "smiley",
"description": "This is a header block built for a large hero image and text",
"supports": {
    "html": false
},
"textdomain": "hero-block",
"editorScript": "file:./build/index.js",
"editorStyle": "file:./build/index.css",
"style": "file:./build/style-index.css"
 }
```

I've compared my code to the gutenberg examples code found here https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples but I can't seem to find any major differences that would cause an issue and I don't see any js errors in the console.

How do I get the remove block menu to appear in my custom block?

UPDATE:
One thing I noticed in the dom is that the blocks that have the menu attached to them have a unique id and various other attributes like what appears below

```
<p id="block-761ca223-cfd6-4dc4-8f28-36c2e1326feb" tabindex="0" role="group" aria-label="Block: Starter Block" data-block="761ca223-cfd6-4dc4-8f28-36c2e1326feb" data-type="create-block/starter-block" data-title="Starter Block" class="wp-block-create-block-starter-block block-editor-block-list__block wp-block is-selected">Starter Block – hello from the editor!</p>
```

And my version is encapsulated by a single div with no attributes.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that I was missing   `{ ...useBlockProps() }` from the encapsulated div.
I was able to resolve the issue by changing the opening div returned in the edit attribute to

```
<div {...useBlockProps()}>
```